# MVC3 Sliding expiration of cookies not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I am using the built in Forms authentication in an MVC3 application. The issue I am currently facing is that the cookies `slidingexpiration` is not working.

The *web.config* file has the following line:

```
<forms loginUrl="/auth" name="authy" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" />
```

note:: I have declared `slidingexpiration` even though the default is true.

Within my code I am making use of the basic Membership Provider class with no extending or modification. My *global.asax* file is using the system default.

There is no point in adding a code example as this is just a base project with no extra code added. I am using the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);` to set the cookies initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx):

> Sliding expiration resets the expiration time for a valid
>   authentication cookie if a request is made and more than half of the
>   timeout interval has elapsed. If the cookie expires, the user must
>   re-authenticate. Setting the SlidingExpiration property to false can
>   improve the security of an application by limiting the time for which
>   an authentication cookie is valid, based on the configured timeout
>   value.

2 very important things to notice in this quote:

1. ... **if a request is made** ...
2. ... **half of the timeout interval** ....

You haven't specified a timeout so the default value of 30 minutes will be used.

Another important thing to notice in this quote:

> Setting the SlidingExpiration property to false can improve the
>   security

but I guess you don't care about security since you have activated it.

---

UPDATE:

Here's a full example illustrating the concept:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("foo", true);
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        return Json(User.Identity.Name + " is still authenticated", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        (function () {
            var caller = arguments.callee.caller;
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("foo")', function (result) {
                    $('#msg').append($('<div/>', { text: result }));
                    caller();
                });
            }, 10000);
        })();
    });
</script>

<div id="msg"></div>
```

web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms 
        loginUrl="/auth" 
        name="authy" 
        path="/" 
        slidingExpiration="true" 
        timeout="1" 
    />
</authentication>
```

No matter how long you stay on the Index view, the user will still be authenticated.

Comment: Apologies I understand that there needs to be a request made and that it needs to be under half of the timeout period. But even with this the cookie is just expiring and the expiration time is not being updated.

Comment: @aspect, well, I don't know. This has always worked for me exactly as the documentation states it. So you must be doing something differently. Though to say. Also I stress on the following fact: **more than half of the timeout**, and not **under half of the timeout** as you stated in your comment. The request must be sent after the half of the timeout period has elapsed if you expect your cookie to be updated, a.k.a you will have to wait 15 minutes before actually starting to see the cookie value change.

Comment: Thats what i meant, i understand how it should work the issue is its not working how it should. I was hoping someone would be able to give me insight into why it not working instead of telling me how it should work.

Comment: @aspect, sorry status no repro for me. You will have to provide the full steps allowing to create a project that illustrates the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Upon adding the `cookieless="UseCookies"` to the web.config forms attributes. The sliding expiry is now working.  I do not understand how this could make any difference but it has done something. I guess it is just one of those quirks.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where my sliding expiration was not working.

I had the path set incorrectly.